# How to add eventlistener in vue and have access to components in this.$refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The structure of my root component is something like this

```
<Header />
<router-view>
 <somecomponent>
   <component A ref="componentA" />
   <component B ref="componentB" />
 </somecomponent>
</router-view>
<Footer />
```

I am using an event bus to communicate between components in the header and components in the router-view as per [adding component to parent from child in vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581181/adding-component-to-parent-from-child-in-vue)

When receiving an event in the somecomponent in router-view, I would like to do something to componentA through this.$refs.componentA.

I add the eventlistener to somecomponent like this:

```
EventBus.$on("someevent", args => {
      this.onSomeEvent(args);
    });
```

and define the method like this:

```
methods: {
    onSomeEvent(args) {
      this.$refs.componentA.doSomething();
    },
```

This works fine until I change the page and then go back to the page with somecomponent.
Then I start getting the error

```
Error in event handler for "someEvent": "TypeError: this.$refs.componentA is undefined"
TypeError: "this.$refs.componentA is undefined"
    onSomeEvent somecomponent.vue
```

But the action "doSomething()" is still executed. So it is as if the eventhandler is triggered twice and on the first run that this.$refs.componentA is undefined, where as it is defined on the second run.

I have tried adding the eventlistener

```
EventBus.$on("someevent", args => {
          this.onSomeEvent(args);
        });
```

to somecomponent's mounted and updated but with the same result.

Any ideas where I should place the eventlistener to avoid the error above?

Comment: Are you able to create a reproduce-able example and link that?  I think you're right that the event is being fired twice.  You could try adding `EventBus.$off('someevent')` to remove the existing event handlers before adding it to see if this fixes it.  Check the docs here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events

Comment: Thanks, It works if I remove the existing event handlers. Here is jsFiddle that shows the event being fire multiple times: https://jsfiddle.net/6tracj3m/  Try hitting 'click me' on Foo, then Home and then Foo again. As you can see it fires the event an increasing number of times as you go back and forth between 'Foo' and 'Home'